# SQLite query with selectionArgs null

Tags: android

I use the String selectionArgs in query() statement. I want set one of selectionArgs to null, as I have not use its. Ex " 
`Cursor cur = sqlite_obj.query(TableName, null, "UID = ? AND Age > ? AND Room = ? AND Adre = ?", new String[] { "31", "" ,"3", ""},     null, null, null, null);`

But I do not use 2nd and 4nd of selectionArgs or 3nd of selectionArgs can null. How I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. For example, post code you have trouble with.

Comment: You can just put null if you do not have any selection arguments over there

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday. As @Sam_k told you, use null, if you aren't using bound parameters (those ones with the **?** placeholders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to use two querys.

```
String where="";
String []params=null;
if(hasAge){
   where="UID = ? AND Age > ?";
   params=new String[] { String.valueOf(iud), String.valueOf(age) };
}else{
   where="UID = ? ";
   params=new String[] { String.valueOf(iud) };
}
Cursor cur = sqlite_obj.query(TableName, null, where, params, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: if I have 5 params. How I do ?

Answer (score 3):

It´s a little bit unclear what exactly You want, but If You just want the tables content, then this is all You need:

```
 Cursor cur = db.query("YourTableName", 
        null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

With this You get a Cursor where You can get all entries inside a table.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way also

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    do {
                        Log.d("tag",""+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COLUMN_NAME)));


                    } while (c.moveToNext());

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor mCursor =db.query("TABLE_NAME", 
                null, 
                null, 
                null,        
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
Cursor cur = sqlite_obj.query(TableName, null, "UID = ? AND Age > ?", new String[] { "31", "54" },     null, null, null, null);
```

Use '?' in the WHERE clause, and in arguments, just enter those values. Hope this helps.